# updating or reloading a UIViewController from another Controller using UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iOS app that it has a mainControllerView, there I create a UINavigationController and then I push into that UINavController a new UIViewController called FirstViewController, and other views.

In short is something like this:

```
MainController(UIVIewController) 
   |  
    --> UINavController 
         | 
          --> FirstViewController(UIViewController)
         |
          --> SecondViewController(UIViewController)
         |
          --> AddViewController
```

Also, inside the FirstViewController I have a UITableView, that UITableView is being fed by CoreData.

Now, I decided to add a "plus" system button on the top-right corner (of the NavigationBar) to add another row into the DB and therefore that should be reflected into the  UITableview.

What I did was create another custom view, called AddViewController which is pushed into the NavController stack when I press that "plus" button. In that View, I just added a few textfields and a button to update the DB, that is working, however, I cannot find a way to update the UITableView, which is inside of FirstViewController, when I press back.

Again in short,

```
UINavController(with FirstViewController)
 1.-When I press the "+" button another UIViewController (AddViewContronller) 
    is pushed
 2.-In that view I present a few UITextfields to be filled.
 3.-I press a "save" button on the NavigationBar, that button save info 
    into the DB and then it goes back the FirstViewController, popping the current
    UIViewController(AddViewController)
 4.-FirstViewController and its tableView is on the main screen again, however
    the rows are still the same.
```

I've been trying to update the FirstViewController when I press the save button in AddViewController, but as I said, I've been unsuccessful.

The option I have not tried is release the FirstViewController when I'm jumping to another UIViewController and then reallocate in the back, but I don't think that it's a good idea as using the NavigationController I can track all my view controllers that are into the stack.

So anybody knows what should I do to refresh/reload a View (UIViewController) from another UIViewController, in my case update FirstViewController view from AddViewController?

Also, I would like to heard if I am in the right track? or what I want to do it can be easily done with another approach like a modal dialog?

Any help it will be very much appreciate

cheers,
Raul

Comment: Do you use NSFetchedResultsController to fill your table view with data?

Comment: no, I just created a method to fetch the data and I thought in calling every time I need to update the TableView. I did this because I didn't know about NSFetchResultsController...now having a quick look into that, it seems the way to go..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to handle the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(dataDidChange)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)dataDidChange {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are not familiar with `UITableView`, you should read [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

And if you use Core Data to populate your `UITableView`, you almost always should use `NSFetchedResultsController`.